# What's the earliest movie with a comedic scene of mistaking a bull for a cow?

Tags: comedy, first-appearance

As a child I saw an American comedy maybe from the 50s/60s about a woman who loses one man after the other by death. In one scene a soon-to-be-dead husband is trying to milk what he mistakes for a cow with fatal consequences. 
Then, in a scene from *Kingpin*, Woody Harelson is drinking self-milked "milk", only to discover it is not, and getting into a serious need for a toothbrush. 
From time to time, whether in advertisment, series or movie, I encounter this pattern of mistaking a bull for a cow.

Which movie might be the oldest one containing it?

Comment: You ask for a list of movies containing a concept, which makes the question too broad. The second question, which movie used this gag first, seems like a reasonable question.

Comment: Also, are you looking for that first movie's title? Or do you already know it?

Comment: Per invalid_id's suggestion, edited to only contain the 2nd question & voted to reopen.

Comment: No, i do not know it, asking for the first occurence of this gag seems more meaningfull than to ask for a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right about this gag being popular. Other than the movies you have already mentioned (*Kingpin* and [*What A Way To Go!*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_a_Way_to_Go!) from 1964 with Shirley MacLaine), this also appears in [*City Slickers II*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_Slickers_II:_The_Legend_of_Curly%27s_Gold) (1994), [*For Richer or Poorer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_Richer_or_Poorer) (1997) and [*Ice Age 3*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_Age:_Dawn_of_the_Dinosaurs) (2009).

But surprisingly, though it's not explicitly shown and only lasts a couple of seconds, the gag was *hinted at* all the way back in **1915**: In Charlie Chaplin's [*The Tramp*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tramp_%28film%29), Charlie works on a farm and is asked by a girl to milk a cow. Ignorantly, he first contemplates placing the bucket under a bull's (quite visible) phallus before realizing his mistake and moving on to a cow, embarrassed.

Comment: great, already 1915!!!